# Using Json to access a specific attribute

Tags: java, android, json

Hello guys i'm reading a page that contain JSON objects with JAVA (Android)

Here is what the page contains :

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Safi, Maroc" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Avenue Hassan II, Safi, Maroc" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1,0 km",
                  "value" : 966
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "2 minutes",
                  "value" : 129
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I know how to read from the page doing this

```
    JSONObject jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    String elements = jArray.getString("rows");
```

the elements string contain that :

```
[{"elements" : [{"distance" : {"text" : "1,0 km","value" : 966},"duration" : {"text" : "2 minutes","value" : 129},"status" : "OK"}]}]
```

But im trying to get the **distance value** which is "**966**"

Thx guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray rows = jObj.getJSONArray("rows");
for(int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
     JSONObject obj = rows.getJSONObject(i);
     JSONArray elements = jObj.getJSONArray("elements");
     for(int j = 0; j < elements.length; j++){
          JSONObject Jobj = elements.getJSONObject(j);
          JSONObject distance = Jobj.getJSONObject("distance");
          int distance_value = distance.getInteger("value");
          JSONObject duration = Jobj.getJSONObject("duration");
          int duration_value = duration.getInteger("value");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at this link:

[How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

But for your particular problem you want to call something like:

```
int value = jArray.getJSONObject("rows").getJSONObject("elements").getJSONArray("distance").getInteger("value");
```

Answer (score 2):

So you are trying to access an entry from the array. See Tutorials or examples. This is basic stuff:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

You need to actually use a [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) (which subclasses JSONObject)